# RenderPartial CActiveDataProvider pagination ajax not working yii

Tags: php, ajax, yii, pagination

My controller code

```
public function actionRead() {
       $criteria=new CDbCriteria(array(                    
                                'order'=>'id desc',
                            ));
        $enP=new CActiveDataProvider('Readss', array(
                'criteria'=>$criteria,
                    'pagination'=>array(
                    'pageSize'=>1,
                ),
            ));
$this->renderPartial('_read', array('data'=>$enP));
}
```

it display the gridview properly ,

my view code

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
                              'id'=>'dfsdfsdf',
                                'dataProvider' => $data,
                               'itemsCssClass' => 'sdfsdfdl',
                                  'ajaxUpdate' => false,
                                'template' => '{summary}{pager}{items}{summary}{pager}',

                                  'columns'=>array(
                                    array(
                                      'header'=>'#',
                                      'value'=>'++$row',
                                      'htmlOptions'=>array(
                                      'style'=>'width:50px;'
                                      )
                                  ),
                                    'name',
                                    array(
                                    'name'=>'Date',
                                    'header'=>'Date',

                                    'value'=>'Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format("d MMM y",strtotime($data["work_date"]))'
                                ),

                                 ),
                               ));
```

But when i click my pagination my page is refressing , what mistake i did here , 
I want to load data on click pagination without page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would work you can just make the 4rd argument true

```
//This will disable jquery being loaded again (use this if you have jquery already loaded 
//means you are calling this in ajax)
//Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery.js'] = false;
//Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery.min.js'] = false;
$this->renderPartial('_read', array('data'=>$enP),false,true);
```

Comment: are you calling this in ajax?

Comment: use the above code, comment the two lines use only renderPartial

Comment: view page source and check whether jquery is loaded and if yes check for error in console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64777/discussion-between-life-hacker-and-dhanush-bala).

Answer (score 0):

In your `CGridView` you indicated to disable `AJAX` by following line:

```
'ajaxUpdate' => false,
```

You must change it to `TRUE`:

```
'ajaxUpdate' => true,
```